# enter multiple String data in java at the same time

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
String username="administrator", iusername="", password="password", ipassword="";
System.out.println("Please login to the system");
System.out.print("\nusername:\t");

iusername = scan.nextLine();
System.out.print("\npassword:\t");
ipassword = scan.nextLine();
```

i want user enter data for two variable (iusername and ipassword)
but i only can enter data for ipassword, because it skip

```
iusername = scan.nextLine();
```

below is the sample of output from IDE

```
username:   username:   

password:   BUILD STOPPED (total time: 12 seconds)
```

it skip my username and go to password

Comment: What are `scan` and `scan2`? It sounds like you've created two separate `Scanner` instances... why? (And why are you initializing your variables and then immediately assigning new values?)

Comment: You're using `scan` and `scan2`. What's the difference?

Comment: using `scan` and `scan2` is because i cannot enter the username variable data and it jump to the password variable @JonSkeet and @jeroenVannevel

Comment: Looks like Scanner class instances. You can resuse the same instance.

Comment: See my answer below, I think you just want it to show the username entered.

Comment: @user2860598 it remain the same,
it skip username also, below is the output:
Please login to the system

username: username: 

password: 
as you all saw it skip my username and go to password
in C++ i can used cin.sync to solve this issue, 
what is the solution i can do for java?

Comment: @wesleylim1993 Edit your question to show what you expect to happen, what is happening and your whole method or class this is in. Without more information we can not help you.

Comment: @user2860598 i have update it :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be used to put new output on new lines automatically.

```
System.out.println("");
```

**Without more code, or a clearer question this is hard to answer.**

```
username = scan.nextLine();
System.out.print("\npassword:\t");
password = scan2.nextLine();
```

Should be, as you can reuse the Scanner class Instance.

```
username = scan.nextLine();
System.out.print("\npassword:\t");
password = scan.nextLine();
```

But **maybe** you want to do

```
username = scan.nextLine(); // Get user input
System.out.println("Username:\t" + username); // Show typed username
password = scan2.nextLine(); // Get user input again
System.out.println("Password:\t" + password); // Show typed password
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I don't catch your point...
I tried this and I'm able to insert both values (iusername and ipassword):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultipleStringInput {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String username = "administrator", iusername = "", password = "password", ipassword = "";
      System.out.println("Please login to the system");
      System.out.print("\nusername:\t");

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      iusername = scan.nextLine();
      System.out.print("\npassword:\t");
      ipassword = scan.nextLine();
      System.out.println(iusername + " " + ipassword);
   }

}
```

I think this code works as expected ("i want user enter data for two variable").
It looks like your IDE is redirecting System.out to your scanner... strange... I suggest you test it from command line.